# SQL Server Agent Job - No History

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL2012 running multiple Jobs successfully except for one.  The one job executes a stored procedures which drops a table and the table gets recreated via an insert statement.  Every morning I see the table empty which leads me to believe it's getting executed but when I look at the History of the job it shows nothing at all.  And I don't get any notifications when the job fails.

I am curious if there is a specific log location I can look to see the job is getting started but something (maybe a backup) starts and kills the job.

Comment: Where you are looking *is* the correct place. If a backup (of `msdb`) was restored over the current version, those logs would be lost.

Comment: I don't think I capping out the History as I can see the history for all my jobs for the last 30 days.  I might looking into logging it's execution somewhere else as a test.